# How can i run a cmd command in java with admin rights?

Tags: java

I want to start mysql server from eclipse and I need admin rights to start it, how can i do this?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Clasa {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String command = "net start MySql55";
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", command);
            pb.inheritIO();
            Process pr = pb.start();
            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really something that a scripting language ([python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486725/how-to-execute-a-command-prompt-command-from-python), [batch file](http://superuser.com/questions/788924/is-it-possible-to-automatically-run-a-batch-file-as-administrator)) would be a better fit for. That being said, you can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596599/run-command-prompt-as-administrator) for more info on doing this in java.

Comment: You can use "runas" command to achieve this. However your current user should have relevant permissions to do that. You can refer this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc771525.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is really something that a scripting language ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486725/how-to-execute-a-command-prompt-command-from-python), [batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/788924/is-it-possible-to-automatically-run-a-batch-file-as-administrator)) would be a better fit for. That being said, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596599/run-command-prompt-as-administrator) for more info on doing this in Java.