# Using python language to acces a cmd window

Tags: python

It is possible to make a python script which opens a cmd window and enters 5 commands one by one, and after waits for an external trigger to continue entering another 2 commands in the same window.

It is posibble? I hope You understand what I ask.
PS: maybe you can share with me a  sample code or something.

Thank you in advance.
M.

Comment: Is it important for you that the terminal actually opens or does it suffice if you only run the commands?

Comment: You can take a look at Python's [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Its not important It can be either way, but maybe the terminal should be on in order to see  the progress of the commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a command prompt command from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486725/how-to-execute-a-command-prompt-command-from-python)

Comment: i guess you want to see them typed in, as if somebody was typing them, right?

Comment: Yes,  something like this if its posible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

What i have done in the past is use Python to write a `.bat` file and run it. And this does produce the result you describe. You can do this like that:

```
import subprocess

with open(r'my_bat_file.bat','w') as fout:
    fout.write('command no1')
    fout.write('command no2')
    ...
    fout.write('command non')
    fout.write('pause')

subprocess.run(r'my_bat_file.bat', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

The `pause` command keeps the cmd open and waiting for a key stroke. When the key even logs, execution of the bat file will continue. If the pause is the last line in your batch file, cmd will close.

Comment: Yes, I know about bat file, but after  4 commands I want to wait  until i command with a trigger  to enter another 2 commands in the same window.

Comment: @Mihail why not add them from the beginning ? They execute sequentially any way

Comment: Because the last 2 commands are activated from an external system such a button or something.

Comment: @Mihail Adding a `pause` command to the shell does not help you either, does it?

Comment: This pause command it like a delay? because with delay will not work, just because I don't have a specific time for the last commands, its entirely depends on the feedback of some device.

Comment: it is not. it pauses until you hit a key with the cmd window on focus

Comment: Yes, It will maybe work, thank you for your help, I will try your suggestions in a few hours And I will tell you.