# How to execute a command in a command window opened in Windows thru python subprocess.popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I would like to execute multiple commands within the command window I opened thru the subprocess.pOpen command ? how to do it ?

Something like

```
p = subprocess.Popen("start cmd /k ", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True )
```

now I want to call multiple commands in the same window I opened.
I don't want to pass the argument as a list since it will only be treated as parameters of the first element in the list.

Comment: Why don't you create a batch file and call that batch file? Or do you need any interaction between that command prompt and this python program

Comment: Please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486725/how-to-execute-a-command-prompt-command-from-python

Comment: If you need interaction or send the commands one by one, whatever Dinesh suggested is good

Comment: I want to issue command based on the messages I am getting into the window. So running a batch file ahead of time is not a solution for me.

Answer (score -1):

Following is the snippet which I keep it handy always to run windows commands.

```
import subprocess
result = []
win_cmd = 'ipconfig'
#shell=True means do not show the command shell
#shell=False means show the command shell
process = subprocess.Popen(win_cmd,
            shell=False,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
for line in process.stdout:
    print (line)
result.append(line)
errcode = process.returncode
for line in result:
    print (line)
```

Comment: [Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256849/354577).