# Python Subprocess cmd

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, subprocess

I am trying to open the CMD with python then get it to run a command.
After lots of trial and error I tested just opening the cmd line with subprocess code below

```
subprocess.call('cmd', '/k')
```

When it brings the cmd prompt up and I try to do a simple command like ll or ls it gives me the 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

is there any way I can open CMD and get it to run a command?

Comment: Um, I'm no windows expert, but I'm pretty sure `ll` and `ls` are unix-isms. I recall they have different names for the windows cmd

Comment: The Unix `ls` equivalent command on Windows is `dir`

Comment: So, hi, if possible, see **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486725/how-to-execute-a-command-prompt-command-from-python)**, I´m not sure, but seems to me is the same question. The user asking for **_How to execute a command prompt command from python_**

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

1.Get the input

2.Then run the system command

```
import os
x = input()
os.system(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why would we want to open a command prompt when we can simply run the needed command using the "subprocess" module.

```
import subprocess
result = []
win_cmd = 'ipconfig'
#shell=True means do not show the command shell
#shell=False means show the command shell
process = subprocess.Popen(win_cmd,
            shell=False,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
for line in process.stdout:
    print (line)
result.append(line)
errcode = process.returncode
for line in result:
    print (line)
```

Comment: [Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256849/354577).