# Sending multiple commands to a bash shell which must share an environment

Tags: python, bash

I am attempting to follow this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5087695/343381

I have a need to execute multiple bash commands within a single environment.  My test case is simple:

```
import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen(['bash'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Write the first command
command = "export greeting=hello\n"
cmd.stdin.write(command)
cmd.stdin.flush() # Must include this to ensure data is passed to child process
result = cmd.stdout.read()
print result

# Write the second command
command = "echo $greeting world\n"
cmd.stdin.write(command)
cmd.stdin.flush() # Must include this to ensure data is passed to child process
result = cmd.stdout.read()
print result
```

What I expected to happen (based on the referenced answer) is that I see "hello world" printed.  What actually happens is that it hangs on the first `cmd.stdout.read()`, and never returns.

Can anyone explain why `cmd.stdout.read()` never returns?

Notes:

- It is absolutely essential that I run multiple bash commands from python within the same environment.  Thus, subprocess.communicate() does not help because it waits for the process to terminate.
- Note that in my real test case, it is not a static list of bash commands to execute.  The logic is more dynamic.  I don't have the option of running all of them at once.

Comment: Ah, see it now; I suspect you need to poll the pipes to see if there is any content at all. You could also try to just push the second command `stdin` pipe without reading from `stdout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. Your first command does not produce any output. So the first read blocks waiting for some.
2. You are using read() instead of readline() -- read() will block until enough data is available.

The following modified code (updated with Martjin's polling suggestion) works fine:

```
import subprocess
import select

cmd = subprocess.Popen(['bash'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

poll = select.poll()
poll.register(cmd.stdout.fileno(),select.POLLIN)

# Write the first command
command = "export greeting=hello\n"
cmd.stdin.write(command)
cmd.stdin.flush() # Must include this to ensure data is passed to child process
ready = poll.poll(500)
if ready:
   result = cmd.stdout.readline()
   print result

# Write the second command
command = "echo $greeting world\n"
cmd.stdin.write(command)
cmd.stdin.flush() # Must include this to ensure data is passed to child process
ready = poll.poll(500)
if ready:
   result = cmd.stdout.readline()
   print result
```

The above has a 500ms timeout - adjust to your needs.

Comment: @MartjinPieters - Apologies (just noticed your comment). Was going to delete, but the read() vs readline() is important.

Comment: Thank you for including the polling code.  For someone who has never had to use that function, it was not obvious how to poll stdout for new data.

Comment: Doesnt work for me on Python 2.7.10 gives AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'