# Displaying output of shell commands with shared environments

Tags: python, shell, python-2.x

Is there any way to display the **output** of a shell command in Python, as the command runs?

I have the following code to send commands to a **specific** shell (in this case, `/bin/tcsh`):

```
import subprocess
import select

cmd = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/tcsh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

poll = select.poll()
poll.register(cmd.stdout.fileno(),select.POLLIN)

# The list "commands" holds a list of shell commands
for command in commands:
  cmd.stdin.write(command)

  # Must include this to ensure data is passed to child process
  cmd.stdin.flush() 

  ready = poll.poll()
  if ready:
     result = cmd.stdout.readline()
     print result
```

Also, I got the code above from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534992/sending-multiple-commands-to-a-bash-shell-which-must-share-an-environment), but I am not sure I understand how the polling mechanism works.

1. What exactly is registered above?
2. Why do I need the variable `ready` if I don't pass any `timeout` to `poll.poll()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [catching stdout in realtime from subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess)

Comment: The post you reference addresses, I think, a different problem than what you have. What command are *you* trying to run? It is a single program? Or are you trying to send multiple commands to a subshell?

Comment: @Robᵩ I need to run multiple commands that share an environment (i.e. keep the shell open, and run multiple commands iteratively). For each command, I would like my program to print stdout and stder on the terminal as the shell commands spit their output

Comment: For example, the first would source a specific shell script, setting up several environment variables (e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc), and a second command runs a program that relies on those environment variables.

Comment: FYI, you might want to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible to display the output of a shell comamand as the command runs. There are two requirements:

1) The command must flush its output.

Many programs buffer their output differently according to whether the output is connected to a terminal, a pipe, or a file. If they are connected to a pipe, they might write their output in much bigger chunks much less often. For each program that you execute, consult its documentation. Some versions of `/bin/cat'`, for example, have the `-u` switch.

2) You must read it piecemeal, and not all at once.

Your program must be structured to one piece at a time from the output stream. This means that you ought not do these, which each read the entire stream at one go:

```
cmd.stdout.read()
for i in cmd.stdout:
list(cmd.stdout.readline())
```

But instead, you could do one of these:

```
while not_dead_yet:
    line = cmd.stdout.readline()

for line in iter(cmd.stdout.readline, b''):
    pass
```

Now, for your three specific questions:

> > Is there any way to display the output of a shell command in Python, as the command runs?

Yes, but only if the command you are running outputs as it runs and doesn't save it up for the end.

> > What exactly is registered above?

The file descriptor which, when read, makes available the output of the subprocess.

> > Why do I need the variable ready if I don't pass any timeout to poll.poll()?

You don't. You also don't need the `poll()`. It is possible, if your `commands` list is fairly large, that might need to `poll()` **both** the stdin and stdout streams to avoid a deadlock. But if your `commands` list is fairly modest (less than 5Kbytes), then you will be OK just writing them at the beginning.

Here is one possible solution:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import select

# Critical: all of this must fit inside ONE pipe() buffer
commands = ['echo Start\n', 'date\n', 'sleep 10\n', 'date\n', 'exit\n']

cmd = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/tcsh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# The list "commands" holds a list of shell commands
for command in commands:
  cmd.stdin.write(command)

  # Must include this to ensure data is passed to child process
  cmd.stdin.flush()

for line in iter(cmd.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line
```