# Using python to start parallel ssh rendering jobs

Tags: python, ssh, blender

I'm writing a script in Python to ssh into a few computers (about ten) and have them start rendering 3d images from Blender. It works fine except the next computers's renders won't start until the previous ones are finished. Is there a way to start the commands and have them all run concurrently on their own machines?

what my code looks like:

```
import os
path = /home/me
comp1 = ['sneffels','1','2'] #computer name, start frame, end frame
comp2 = ['bierstadt','3','4']
comp3 = ['diente','5','6']

os.system("ssh igp@" + str(comp1[0]) + " blender -b "+ str(path) +" -s " + str(comp1[1]) + " -e " + str(comp1[2]) + " -a")

os.system("ssh igp@" + str(comp2[0]) + " blender -b "+ str(path) +" -s " + str(comp2[1]) + " -e " + str(comp2[2]) + " -a")

os.system("ssh igp@" + str(comp3[0]) + " blender -b "+ str(path) +" -s " + str(comp3[1]) + " -e " + str(comp3[2]) + " -a")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `os.system` doesn't return until the program is done, and `ssh` isn't done until the command you gave it is done.

This is one of many reasons not to use `os.system`—as [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) explicitly says:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section in the subprocess documentation for some helpful recipes.

In `subprocess`, you can create a bunch of subprocesses, and then join them all after they've all been kicked off. For example:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen("ssh igp@" + str(comp1[0]) + " blender -b "+ str(path) +" -s " + str(comp1[1]) + " -e " + str(comp1[2]) + " -a", shell=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("ssh igp@" + str(comp2[0]) + " blender -b "+ str(path) +" -s " + str(comp2[1]) + " -e " + str(comp2[2]) + " -a", shell=True)
p3 = subprocess.Popen("ssh igp@" + str(comp3[0]) + " blender -b "+ str(path) +" -s " + str(comp3[1]) + " -e " + str(comp3[2]) + " -a", shell=True)
p1.wait()
p2.wait()
p3.wait()
```

That probably isn't the best way to do this. Read the subprocess docs to understand why `shell=True` and passing a string is usually not as good as passing a `list` of parameters, other ways to manage your subprocesses, etc.. But meanwhile, this is probably the simplest change from what you already have.

Another alternative is to not shell out to the `ssh` command in the first place, but instead use something like [`paramiko`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) to spawn the remote processes from within Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) package.  A simple example that might help you can be found [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/simplistic-python-thread-example/) on the Salty Crane blog.  It should allow you to run all your processes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) your calls. I prepared a little example that just echos something (you can change it to ssh). I hope it's clear enough so you can get the idea

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
import os
import random

ips = ["192.168.1.25", "192.168.1.26", "192.168.1.27"]

def run(ip, otherParameter):
    os.system("echo %s with other parameter %s" % (ip, otherParameter))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for ip in ips:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run, args=[ip, random.randint(0, 10)])
        thread.run()
```

Also, instead of os.system, you should take a look to the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, or even better, to use something intended to run ssh commands, take a look to the [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) module.

Comment: Of course this works, but it seems a little silly to create a thread just to wait on each process, given that it's so trivial to split process creation and waiting up so that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) should do the trick.

Check out this previous answer:  [How can I run an external command asynchronously from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636561/how-can-i-run-an-external-command-asynchronously-from-python)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just putting `+ " & "` at the end of each `os.system(...)` ?

You don't seem too bothered if each `blender` works or not.

From the look of it you could just do it in a shell script.

You could install something like `beanstalkd` and have your 10 servers each running a worker that pulls off jobs from the shared queue. Then have your job-dispatcher put on jobs that mention the filename,start-frame, end-frame.

A benefit being that when a consumer finishes they can put their status back on the queue.

Otherwise you'll have issues knowing whether one of the subprocesses failed etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a tool like pssh.
This tool uses multi-threads and performs quickly.
you can read more about it [here](http://www.tecmint.com/execute-commands-on-multiple-linux-servers-using-pssh/).