# How to write a python script that test my c++?

Tags: python, instrumentation

Say I wanna test my c++ code but I don't want to do it by hand. I realize I can write a python script that can test my code for me. So I want to test this c++ code for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string line;
   cin >> line;
   cout << line << endl;
}
```

Here is the python script that I tried to test this c++ code:

```
import subprocess as sb

sb.call("g++ main.cpp", shell=True)
sb.call("./a.out", shell=True)
sb.call("chocolate", shell=True)
```

This create the `a.out` executable file but it doesn't allow me to run my program. How can I make this work? Or is there something better that I can do?

Comment: Removing "C++" tag, as your question is not about how to do something in C++, but how to do something in Python - even if you put some C++ code in the question, that is not the code you are asking about [directly].

Comment: You could use `subprocess.pipe` and `Popen.communicate`, perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python executing shell command doesn't terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196288/python-executing-shell-command-doesnt-terminate)

Comment: Why do you want to test your C++ code with python script? Is there any special reason for that? I think it is more natural and easier to use C++ unit testing libraries like [boots.test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/test/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: @BorisSerebrov We have an entire test team that writes tests for c++ programs in python. These tests drive the C++ at the command line level and by using a foreign function interface when appropriate. This is not C++ unit testing of course (we do that too) but it is a major component of testing. Putting "boost" and "easy" in the same sentence may also be violating natural law.

Comment: Your code works. ./a.out is called and when I type in a word then hit <enter>, it prints the line and then crashes on the next call. I presume that you want more control of the input and output? For that, use the `Popen` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing can get complicated but as a minimum you can use the `subprocess.Popen` object to manage the input and output of the program. Here is a minimalist test suite

```
import subprocess as sb
import threading

def timeout():
    print('timeout')
    exit(3)

sb.check_call("g++ main.cpp", shell=True)
t = threading.Timer(10, timeout)
proc = sb.Popen("./a.out", shell=True, stdin=sb.PIPE, stdout=sb.PIPE,
    stderr=sb.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate('hello\n')
t.cancel()
assert proc.returncode == 0
assert out == 'hello\n'
assert err == ''
sb.check_call("chocolate", shell=True)
```