# Start and Stop external process from python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, external-process

Is there a way to start and stop a process from python? I'm talking about a continues process that I stop with ctrl+z when normally running. I want to start the process, wait for some time and then kill it. I'm using linux.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228) is not like mine because there, the user only needs to run the process. I need to run it and also stop it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?rq=1

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted thanks to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636561/how-can-i-run-an-external-command-asynchronously-from-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to start the process, wait for some time and then kill it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_call(['command', 'arg 1', 'arg 2'],
                          timeout=some_time_in_seconds)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired: 
    print('subprocess has been killed on timeout')
else:
    print('subprocess has exited before timeout')
```

See [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1191374/4279)

Comment: Elegant - avoids any need to explicitly call `kill`. However, it should be noted that this is for Python > 3.3 - to use it in Python 2.7 you need to make use of the [subprocess32 backport module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `os.kill` function to send `-SIGSTOP` (-19) and `-SIGCONT` (-18)

Example (unverified):

```
import signal
from subprocess import check_output

def get_pid(name):
    return check_output(["pidof",name])

def stop_process(name):
    pid = get_pid(name)
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGSTOP)

def restart_process(name):
    pid = get_pid(name)
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGCONT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [Process](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) module:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import time

def sleeper(name, seconds):
    print "Sub Process %s ID# %s" % (name, os.getpid())
    print "Parent Process ID# %s" % (os.getppid())
    print "%s will sleep for %s seconds" % (name, seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    child_proc = Process(target=sleeper, args=('bob', 5)) 
    child_proc.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    child_proc.terminate()
    #child_proc.join()
    #time.sleep(2)
    #print "in parent process after child process join"
    #print "the parent's parent process: %s" % (os.getppid())
```

Comment: Where do I start my external process?