# Execute python file with variables

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system

I want to pass the two variables to another python file, i dont want to start it as a sub process. 
**I want the two processes to run apart** as file1 has alot of more calculations to do and cannot wait for file2's operations to complete.

## FILE1.PY

```
include os
name="one"
status="on"
os.system('F:\PythonSub\file2.py' name status)
```

## FILE2.PY

```
include sys
name=sys.argv[0]
send=sys.argv[1]
print(send, name)
```

The above code returns

```
send=sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run an external command asynchronously from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636561/how-can-i-run-an-external-command-asynchronously-from-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import os
name="one"
status="on"
os.system('F:\PythonSub\file2.py %s %s' % (name status))
```

Comment: include ? or i miss a new feature

Comment: should be `import`

Comment: Ah just copy pasting the OP! Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module (examples on that link). It supports starting processes asynchronously (**which** `os.system` **doesn't**), and passing arguments as parameters. Looks like you'll need something like:

```
subprocess.call(["F:\PythonSub\file2.py", name, status])
```

You may want to redirect the `stdin`/`stdout` streams if you want to get output from the process, and the `shell` option may be useful.

Edit: **This is wrong**, as `subprocess.call` invokes synchronously, not asynchronously. You should use the approach described in the linked duplicate instead.

Comment: Instead of redirecting the `stdout` stream to get the output, you should use `subprocess.check_output` instead of `subprocess.call`