# How to play a sound file in python using subprocess without stopping the program?

Tags: python, audio, subprocess

For my program, I've been using `subprocess` to play my .wav files for my Python 3 program. However, when the sound is played, the program waits until the audio file is done playing before it runs the rest of the program.

I know for winsound and pygame there are ways to play sounds in sync with the program running, but I would prefer to stick with using `subprocess` because pygame hasn't been working out for me and I can't use winsound because I'm on a mac.

Here's what I have:

```
import subprocess
```

`subprocess.call(["afplay", "sounds/dit.wav"])`

Comment: Don't use the convenience functions of `subprocess`, they usually wait for the process to terminate. Use `Popen()` directly!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run an external command asynchronously from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636561/how-can-i-run-an-external-command-asynchronously-from-python)