# Why can I only use the await keyword inside of async function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Suppose I have code like this

```
async def fetch_text() -> str:
    return "text "

async def show_something():
    something = await fetch_text()
    print(something)
```

Which is fine. But then I want to clean the data, so I do

```
async def fetch_text() -> str:
    return "text "

def fetch_clean_text(text: str) -> str:
    text = await fetch_text()
    return text.strip(text)

async def show_something():
    something = fetch_clean_text()
    print(something)
```

(I could clean text inside `show_something()`, but let's assume that `show_something()` can print many things and doesn't or shouldn't know the proper way of cleaning them.)

This is of course a `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function`.  But—if this code could run—while the `await` expression is not placed inside a coroutine function, it is *executed* in the context of one. Why this behavior is not allowed?

I see one pro in this design; in my latter example, you can't see that `show_something()`'s body is doing something that can result in its suspension. But if I were to make `fetch_clean_text()` a coroutine, not only would it complicate things but would probably also reduce performance. It just makes little sense to have another coroutine that doesn't perform any I/O by itself. Is there a better way?

Comment: So, what actually prevents you from cleaning the text with a pure function *after* you have fetched it?

Comment: Shortly, a normal function cannot be scheduled but `await` needs schedule. As the above suggestted, you can use a pure function after fetching.

Comment: @taras this is just an example code. suppose I'm writing a library that fetches titles for URLs, but handles special cases such as yutube's URLs separately, fetching stuff using the API. So now I have `my_library.fetch_title(url)` that makes a lot of internal calls that eventually lead to some IO. Now if I was to make it also async-compatible, I'd (probably?) have to duplicate half of my code, adding `async` and `await` stuff to methods, and in most cases doing so would probably make little sense.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I see one pro in this design; in my latter example, you can't see that
>   show_something()'s body is doing something that can result in its
>   suspension.

That's exactly why it designed this way. Writing concurrent code can be very tricky and asyncio authors decided that it's critically important to always explicitly mark places of suspend in code.

[This article](https://lukasa.co.uk/2016/07/The_Function_Colour_Myth/) explains it in details (you can start from "Get To The Point Already" paragraph).

> But if I were to make fetch_clean_text() a coroutine, not only would
>   it complicate things but would probably also reduce performance.

You need coroutines almost exclusively when you deal with I/O. I/O always takes much-much more time than overhead for using coroutines. So I guess it can be said - no, comparing to I/O you already deal with, you won't lose any significant amount of execution time for using coroutines.

> Is there a better way?

Only way I can suggest: is to maximally split logic that deals with I/O (async part) from rest of the code (sync part).

```
from typing import Awaitable

def clean_text(text: str) -> str:
    return text.strip(text)

async def fetch_text() -> Awaitable[str]:
    return "text "

async def fetch_clean_text(text: str) -> Awaitable[str]:
    text = await fetch_text()
    return clean_text(text)

async def show_something():
    something = await fetch_clean_text()
    print(something)
```

Comment: How do we start (and _await_ ?) this whole flow?

Comment: @javadba you should run an event loop that will start to execute coroutines. The Easiest way to do it is to call [asyncio.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run).

Comment: @mod can someone pls empty the edit queue for this question? i'm guessing a trillion ppl would like Mikhail Gerasimov's question to be worked into the answer - at least that's what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 41):

You can only use `await` in an `async` environment. Try changing the sync function to `async`:

```python
import asyncio

whatever = . . .

async def function(param) -> asyncio.coroutine:
  await param

asyncio.run(function(whatever))
```

Simple and easy.

Comment: What if the async method is part of a class?