# I tried to create a function in python but when creating that function it gives me a syntax error, and I cannot find where that error is

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to create a function that will toggle between the custom prefix and a default prefix. However, I receive a syntax error from it.
Here is the function I am trying to create:

```
@client.event
async def prefixCheck():
    global used_prefix
    if prefixes.json[custom_prefix] != default_prefix[0]:
        used_prefix = prefixes.json[custom_prefix]
        return 0
    if prefixes.json[custom_prefix] == default_prefix[0]:
        used_prefix = default_prefix[0]
        return 0
```

Here is the error I received:

```
C:\Users\ttuser\Desktop\bot>C:/Users/ttuser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/python.exe c:/Users/ttuser/Desktop/bot/bot.py
  File "c:\Users\ttuser\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 18
    async def prefixCheck():
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the full code with the exception of the token at the request of a user:

```
import discord
import os
import json
import getrolemod as grm
#getrolemod is a module that gets the id of roles
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

default_prefix = ["m!"]
guild_owner = discord.Guild.owner_id

bot_mod_role_id = client.event(await grm.get_rid(ctx, "Muffin Bot")

def prefixCheck():
    global used_prefix
    if prefixes.json[custom_prefix] != default_prefix[0]:
        used_prefix = prefixes.json[custom_prefix]
        return 0
    if prefixes.json[custom_prefix] == default_prefix[0]:
        used_prefix = default_prefix[0]
        return 0

prefixCheck()

@client.event
async def setprefix(ctx, arg):
    if message.content == (used_prefix + "setprefix " + arg):
        if (int(ctx.message.author.id) == int(guild_owner)) or (get_role(bot_mod_role_id) in ctx.message.author.roles):
            with open('prefixes.json') as f:
                prefixes = json.load(f)
            'prefixes.json'[ctx.prefix] = arg
            with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(prefixes, f)
            prefixCheck()
            await ctx.channel.send(f"The server prefix has been set to **arg**.")
        elif (int(ctx.message.author.id) == int(guild_owner)) or (get_role(bot_mod_role_id) in ctx.message.author.roles):
            await ctx.message.channel.send("You do not have permissions to do this command.")
```

I removed @client.event in the line before **async def prefixCheck():** and async in that line.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: He is using Python 3.9 This is visible in the traceback

Comment: muffin guy Can you please share your full code? I might be able to help then.

Comment: you probably missed a bracket somewhere before the function definition

Comment: You are wrong in the first line too!
Toggle prefixes is not a client event, when you use the

    @client.event
decorator you have to use client events like on_ready, on_member_update etc.
prefixCheck should be a basic function, and also if you will put more code i'll be able to help you more.

Comment: I updated the post to show the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a closing parenthesis in this line:

```
bot_mod_role_id = client.event(await grm.get_rid(ctx, "Muffin Bot")
```

should be:

```
bot_mod_role_id = client.event(await grm.get_rid(ctx, "Muffin Bot"))
```

Comment: When I add the parenthesis, I get the error **SyntaxError: 'await' outside function**.

Comment: yeah, the error tells you your mistake. you cannot use await outside async functions, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027030/why-can-i-only-use-the-await-keyword-inside-of-async-function)