# SyntaxError: 'await' outside function with `async for`

Tags: python, asynchronous, asyncpraw

I'm not very good with API and async whatnot but this piece of code is literally taken right from the [asyncpraw documentation](https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/quick_start.html), yet it's producing an error. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help.

```
import asyncpraw

reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit(
    client_id="CLIENT_ID",
    client_secret="CLIENT_SECRET",
    user_agent="USER_AGENT",
)
print(reddit.read_only)

subreddit = await reddit.subreddit("ProgrammerHumor")
async for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):
    print(submission.title)
```

It's supposed to print the top ten posts on reddit from r/programmerhumor

[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc1Oq.png)

Edit:

I changed line 10 to this:

```
async def getSubreddit():
  return await reddit.subreddit("ProgrammerHumor")
subreddit = getSubreddit()
```

Got this

[Error #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LewKM.png)

Comment: Edit your post to quote the error message that you receive.

Comment: I'm using python v3.8

Comment: I added the pic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I only use the await keyword inside of async function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027030/why-can-i-only-use-the-await-keyword-inside-of-async-function)

Comment: It seems to be a solution, but I'm not sure how to integrate that into my program.
I edited the above code to the best of my ability, but the result is about the same