# sox create and play tone only on left or right channel

Tags: python, sox

I am trying to create a tone in python and play it only on either the left channel or right channel. I can't figure out how to specify playing on the chosen channel.

Here is my code so far:

```
import os

frequency = 1000 #hz

duration = 2000 #milliseconds

os.system('play -n synth %s sin %s' % (duration/1000, frequency))
```

I have experimented with "remix" but haven't been successful.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest getting sox to output what you want first before adding to your python code.  This should do what you want (left first, then right).

```
play -n -c 2 synth 2 sin 1000 remix 1 0
play -n -c 2 synth 2 sin 1000 remix 0 1
```

It's possible you might also have an issue with the default device for sox.  `play` is simply an alias for `sox -d` i.e. using the default device for output.  To check this, or if you want the output to go to a file, you can use this:

```
sox -n -c 2 left.wav synth 2 sin 1000 remix 1 0
sox -n -c 2 right.wav synth 2 sin 1000 remix 0 1
```

Your python code could incorporate this like so:

```
import os    

frequency = 1000 #hz

duration = 2000 #milliseconds

os.system('play -n -c 2 synth %s sin %s remix 1 0' % (duration/1000, frequency))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there any way to make this non-blocking, i.e. start the sound playing and do other stuff while the sound is playing, versus wait until the sound is played to start anything else?

Comment: Yes, if you use `subprocess.Popen()` instead - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/636570/12744