# How to get the results of long running commands in pypsexec?

Tags: python, windows, psexec

I'm using [pypsexec](https://pypi.org/project/pypsexec/) to connect to a remote Windows machine. I've to find a list of files with a certain extension. This is what I'm doing right now.

```
command = "dir /b/s *.py"
client.run_executable("cmd.exe", arguments=f"/c {command}", asynchronous=True)
```

I wasn't receiving any responses at first when I didn't use the asynchronous parameter. Having read the documentation, I can see that long-running tasks (like mine) should use this parameter. However, it doesn't provide explicit instructions on how to get the output after the job is finished.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you can't get the output. See https://github.com/jborean93/pypsexec/blob/master/pypsexec/client.py#L436-L466

```py
if not interactive and not asynchronous:
    [...] # Here is where stdout and stderr is set
else:
    stdout_out = None
    stderr_bytes = None

[...] # Here is some code that doesn't change stdout_out or stderr_bytes

return stdout_out, stderr_bytes, return_code
```

As you can see when using `asynchronous=True` the stdout and stderr will always be `None`

Comment: That's bad to hear. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @shn Not really, you could, however, use `subprocess` to run the command. And if you want to run it asynchronously take a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61254536/17398665